# Add letters on mouse cursor doesn't work for Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, cross-browser

I want to create a little javascript piece, that:

1) Let's you select a letter by either clicking on it or pressing the key on the keyboard

2) On leftclick in a specified area adds the letter to the mouse cursor and if the ALT-Key is pressed deletes the letter

3) Highlights the selection/clears the selection when clicked or pressed

The code so far is working fine for the most part, but only in Chrome. Firefox highlights on click, but otherwise refuses participation.

```
var letter = "";
var index = 1;
var buchstaben = document.getElementsByClassName("buchstabe");

function blackmailer(){
    // get mouse coordinates
    var clientx = event.layerX;
    var clienty = event.layerY;

    //create a div, give it an id that is stored in index
    var tag = document.createElement("div");
    tag.setAttribute("id", index);
    tag.setAttribute("class", "bStabe");
    // Listener to remove div, if clicked while holding ALT
    tag.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
        if(event.altKey){
            var parent = document.getElementById("check");
            parent.removeChild(this);
        }
    });
    // set position absolute and give it mouse coordinates (puts it on mouse position)
    tag.style.position="absolute";
    tag.style.left= (clientx-5) + "px";
    tag.style.top = (clienty-15) + "px";

    // add text to div element
    var text = document.createTextNode(letter);
    tag.appendChild(text);
    var element = document.getElementById("check");
    element.appendChild(tag);


    index +=1;  
};

function clearSelections(){

    for(var i = 0; i<buchstaben.length;i++){
        buchstaben[i].style.background = "white";
        changeLetter("");
    }
};

function keyboardTaste(){

    /*
     * Create letter of keypress and store it in aLetter
     */
    var x = event.which;
        x = event.keyCode;
    var aLetter = String.fromCharCode(x);
    /*
     * get div with the ID of aLetter
     */
    var letterDiv =document.getElementById(aLetter);

    // Clear all previous Selections
    clearSelections();

        /*
         * Loop through all elements of the array, get the id of the
         * array at position 'i'. 
         */

    for(var i = 0; i<buchstaben.length; i++){
        var idtag = buchstaben[i].id;
        /*
         * if the id is the same as the pressed letter AND the pressed key
         * is different from the stored variable "letter", change the background
         * color (mark active) of the div element and change the stored letter
         * to the pressed letter
         */
        if(idtag === aLetter && letter != aLetter){
            letterDiv.style.background = "red";
            changeLetter(aLetter);
            break;}

        /*
         * if the stored letter is the same as the letter pressed, 'deselect' the
         * letter
         */     
        else if(aLetter === letter){
                clearSelection();
                changeLetter("");   
                break;}
            }

    };

function mausSelektion(banana){

    if(banana != letter){
        clearSelections();
        document.getElementById(banana).style.background="red";
        changeLetter(banana);
    }
    else
    if(banana === letter){
        clearSelections();
        changeLetter("");
    }};




function changeLetter(banana){
    letter = banana;
};



function changeLetter(banana){
    letter = banana;
};
```

The HTML file contains the area 'check', in which letters will be added.

It also contains all the letters in a 'container' box for styling purposes, that call upon the script for selection.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<head>
    <title>Testseite</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    <script src="myscripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="aufg_1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
 <html>
    <body id="body" onmousemove="test()" onkeypress="keyboardTaste()">

            <div id="gluedOn" >
                this be glued onto the mouse
                </div>


            <div id="check" onclick="blackmailer()">

            </div>

            <div id="letterbox">
                <div class="buchstabe" id="a" onclick="mausSelektion(this.id)">A</div>
                <div class="buchstabe" id="b" onclick="mausSelektion(this.id)">B</div>
                <div class="buchstabe" id="c" onclick="mausSelektion(this.id)">C</div>
                <div class="buchstabe" id="d" onclick="mausSelektion(this.id)">D</div>
                <div class="buchstabe" id="e" onclick="mausSelektion(this.id)">E</div>
                <div class="buchstabe" id="f" onclick="mausSelektion(this.id)">F</div>
                <div class="buchstabe" id="g" onclick="mausSelektion(this.id)">G</div>
                <div class="buchstabe" id="h" onclick="mausSelektion(this.id)">H</div>
                <div class="buchstabe" id="i" onclick="mausSelektion(this.id)">I</div>
                <div class="buchstabe" id="j" onclick="mausSelektion(this.id)">J</div>
                <div class="buchstabe" id="k" onclick="mausSelektion(this.id)">K</div>
                <div class="buchstabe" id="l" onclick="mausSelektion(this.id)">L</div>
                <div class="buchstabe" id="m" onclick="mausSelektion(this.id)">M</div>
                <div class="buchstabe" id="n" onclick="mausSelektion(this.id)">N</div>
                <div class="buchstabe" id="o" onclick="mausSelektion(this.id)">O</div>
                <div class="buchstabe" id="p" onclick="mausSelektion(this.id)">P</div>
                <div class="buchstabe" id="q" onclick="mausSelektion(this.id)">Q</div>
                <div class="buchstabe" id="r" onclick="mausSelektion(this.id)">R</div>
                <div class="buchstabe" id="s" onclick="mausSelektion(this.id)">S</div>
                <div class="buchstabe" id="t" onclick="mausSelektion(this.id)">T</div>
                <div class="buchstabe" id="v" onclick="mausSelektion(this.id)">V</div>
                <div class="buchstabe" id="w" onclick="mausSelektion(this.id)">W</div>
                <div class="buchstabe" id="x" onclick="mausSelektion(this.id)">X</div>
                <div class="buchstabe" id="y" onclick="mausSelektion(this.id)">Y</div>
                <div class="buchstabe" id="z" onclick="mausSelektion(this.id)">Z</div>
                <div class="buchstabe" id="ß" onclick="mausSelektion(this.id)">ß</div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have no experience with cross-browser programming (yet), so any hints would be greatly appreciated! If possible, it should be pure javascript, but in the end functionality is more important. banana for scale.

Answer (score 0):

After consulting the firefox web console, this code will create a lot of "Reference Errors - Undefined".

To resolve the issue with all the browsers, it's necessary to create (event) parameters for the functions.

Like so:

```
    function blackmailer(event){ }
```

And the coresponding HTML:

```
<div id="check" onclick="blackmailer(event)">
```

This is necessary, because we call the

```
event.screen
```

For 'event' to work, we actually have to give the function a parameter which IS the event. That solved my problem.